# Question about weight painting influence

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to weight paint my character and don't understand how the weight values are working. In the first screenshot, I have a bone from the spine selected and have the shoulders painted completely red. When I move that bone, the shoulders move how I want. But when I select the arm bone, as shown in the second screenshot, it is still influencing the shoulder.

If one bone is influencing 100%, shouldn't that make other bones' influence 0%? Also, is there a way to see numerically what the influence values are on vertex?

Answer (score 1):

The amount a bone influences a vertex is the proportion of weight that bone contributes to the *total* weight on the vertex.

For example, if a vertex has three bones each with weight 1.0, then each bone has an influence of 1/3, since each one contributes 1.0 to the total weight 3.0.

Another example: if bone A has weight 0.75 and bone B has weight 0.5, then bone A has 60% (0.75/1.25) of the influence and bone B has 40% (0.5/1.25).

If the total weight on a vertex is 1, then the weight is the same as the amount of influence. In this case the weights are said to be *normalized*. You can normalize all vertices by going to <kbd>Mesh > Weights > Normalize All</kbd> while in Edit mode.

> Also, is there a way to see numerically what the influence values are on vertex?

In Edit mode, select one vertex and open the sidebar (<kbd>N</kbd>). You can see the weights in the Item tab. You can also press the <kbd>Normalize</kbd> button to normalize them here.

[image: Sidebar showing Vertex Weights section]

Comment: Thanks for the help @scurest
You mention in your example a bone having a weight of 1.5. How do you get a weight above 1.0? I figured blue meant a weight of zero and red meant 1.0 and also the brush doesn't go above 1.0. Also, how does a brush strength relate to weight?

Comment: Oh, you can't lol. I fixed that example.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what differentiates brush weight and strength?

Comment: To add to scurest's answer, if a vertex is part of one vertex group only, even if the weight is 0.01, the bone will have a full influence of 100% on it

Comment: In Brush settings, weight is the "Target Value" you will assign, while Strenght affects how many strokes are needed to reach that Target value. In example, if the brush weight is set to 1.0 and the Strenght is 0.1, you will need 10 strokes to go from 0.0 to full 1.0 weight. If the weight is 0.1 and the Strenght is 1, you will reach 0.1 after the first stroke, but the weight will not raise above 0.1, no matter how many strokes you paint.

Comment: @moonboots Right, since it contributes 100% of the total weight. There is a threshold below which it stops counting though (0.0001 I think).